# Aligining quotes (images and text) with flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

Consider this markup for a quote containing 3 parts: content, author's name and an image.

```
    <div class="quote">
      <div class="content"> <p>"Quote content goes here"</p> </div>
      <div class="quote-img"> <img src="https://www.outsystems.com/PortalTheme/img/UserImage.png?24179"> </div>
      <div class="author"> <p>Author's name</p> </div>
    </div>
```

**Expected layout**

[image: Expected layout]

Notice in small screens how the author div should be the footer, and in larger screens it should be aligned with the image.

How can I do this using flexbox? Here's what I have so far:

[JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/rasesiyefi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Flexbox can't do that, unless the height of the wrapper is known.

Comment: You want a two dimension layout, `flexbox` is meant for column **or** row direction, not both.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141646/flexbox-layout-pattern-3-squares-ordered-1-large-left-2-small-right-stacked

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz But I understand a div can be both a container and an item, so I thought there was a trick to it. Not sure if flexbox is the best option, though.